# The Electric Quadrupole

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits, multipole-expansion

I've read the following sentence:
"Every electric circuit with two pairs of accessible terminals is called a quadrupole."

I was wondering why does it happen that the multipole expansion gives us a quadrupole in an electric circuit with these properties... Can we see each pair of terminals as oppositely oriented dipoles? If so why? My main problem is to make sense of charges when thinking about the electric circuit itself.

Comment: Read the "following sentence" *where*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess; you are mixing up quadripoles and quadrupoles.

Quadripoles are two-port networks used in electric circuit analysis. The original German word is "Vierpol Theorie", which means Four-pol because of 4 Poles.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-port_network

Quadrupoles are related to multipole expansion used in electromagnetic, atomic orbital,.. theory.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole

Comment: Yeah, I mixed up the names because I'm not studying in English. I really don't know much about electric circuit analysis and I thought there could be any relationship, thank you :)